# problems with sqlite3_prepare() Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

When this program runs this code to connect to the SQLite database it can passes through the path test, opens the database, the SQL works on the actual database. Then it fails when it tries to do the sqlite3_prepare statement. It exits with a code of 1 - SQL error or missing database. It will then continue on with the program all the way until it tries to read the data it got from the database. It then fails because it never got anything because it came back with an SQL error or missing database code from the sqlite3_prepare statement. I'm looking for the part of the code which is wrong/I could correct to make it succeed on the sqlite3_prepared statement.

```
#import "contactDAO.h"
#import "contact.h"

@implementation contactDAO

- (NSMutableArray *) getList{
NSMutableArray *contactArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
@try {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iFLY.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured.");
    }
    const char *sql = "SELECT reportNumber, dateEntered, country, state FROM CONTACT";
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement");
    }

    //
    while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
        Contact *contactInfo;

        contactInfo.reportNumber = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 0);
        contactInfo.dateEntered = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 1);
        contactInfo.country = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];
        contactInfo.state = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,3)];
        /*contactInfo.county = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,4)];
        contactInfo.town = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,5)];
        contactInfo.policeContact = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,6)];
        contactInfo.policeReport = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 7);
        contactInfo.autopsyNumber = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 8);
        contactInfo.lastSeen = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 9);
        contactInfo.victimName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,10)]; */
        [contactArray addObject:contactInfo];
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
}
@finally {
    return contactArray;
} 
}

@end
```

Thanks!

Comment: you need to copy your db in document dir then you can use it

Comment: Did you ever found an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a declaration of 'db', which would look as follows:

```
sqlite3 *db;
```

I can also see a clarity problem with this:

```
if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
```

Since your code will continue to evaluate stuff even when a problem is found, since you don't return after those parts where you try to catch an error.

Your order of execution should look a little like this:

```
if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) 
{        
    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;        
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) { /* do stuff here */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have said that db was defined in the header file.

Comment: Well then be a little more specific about what happens in `sqlite3_prepare` so we can help you.

Comment: sqlite3_prepare exits with a 1 or SQL error / missing database. I'm trying to get it to connect to the database and pull information from the CONTACT table.

Comment: If it exists with a '1' then that's as intended. As for the latter, try using `sqlite3_prepare_v2` is it is the preferred function.

Comment: How can I get it to move from '1' to '0'?

Comment: 1 == YES/TRUE, 0 == NO/FALSE -- why would you want it to evaluate to false?

Answer (score 0):

Is CONTACT a view or a table? I had a similar issue getting the same error when selecting from a view. When I changed this to a table, it worked.